# "Merge" two signatures of operator () overload into one in a template class, how?

Tags: c++, class, object, templates, c++17

Let's suppose I have the following class in an header file `header.h`:

```
#pargma once

#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct foo
 {
  // Utils struct
  template <class T, class... Ts>
  struct is_any: std::disjunction <std::is_same <T, Ts>... >{};

  // Standard case
  template <class T_os, class T, class... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_any
  <T_os, std::ostream, std::ostringstream>::value>>
  const foo& operator () ( T_os& os, const T& first, const Args&... args ) const { os << "hello"; return *this; }

  // Default std::ostream = std::cout case
  template <class T, class... Args> 
  const foo& operator () ( const T& first, const Args&... args ) const { std::cout << "hello"; return *this; }
 };
```

I defined a `struct` in which I overloaded the `()` operator two times: in the "standard case" the template is enabled if the `T_os` type is one of this list (`std::ostream`, `std::ostringstream`) and a message is sent to output using the `T_os os` object. In the "Default std::ostream = std::cout case" the template is called if `T_os` is not explicitly present and a message is sent to output using the `std::ostream std::cout` object.

A simple usage in main is:

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
 {
  foo foo_obj;
  
  // Standard case
  foo_obj ( std::cout, "first", "second" );

  // Default std::ostream = std::cout case
  foo_obj ( "first", "second" );
 }
```

I want to know if it would be possible to merge the "standard case" operator `()` overload within the "Default std::ostream = std::cout case" operator `()` overload, in order to be able to perform the two operations shown in `main` using only an operator `()` overload instead of two. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know `if constexpr` and how it works?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik not so well, never used it so far. Could you provide me a complete example contextualized within the struct I posted? Thanks, of course I would upvote it.

Comment: `is_same<T, std::ostream>` will probably not be useful very often. Are you sure you don't want `is_base_of<std::ostream, T>`? Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/G1nGfE75z)?

Comment: How about calling the first from the second (and supplying std::cout as the first argument) ? You will have 2 methods, but very little code duplication.

Comment: @TedLyngmo nitpick, you probably mean `is_convertible<T&, std::ostream&>`.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Hmm, no, something convertible to an `ostream&` is not necessarily capable of streaming

Comment: @TedLyngmo True in the same sense as it is for `is_base_of`. The derived class can disable streaming. The `is_base_of` suggestioned seemed to be getting at whether T "is-a" ostream which is spelled `is_convertible` in our language (because of course it is). (But, with `is_convertible` one can effect the conversion and stream. One cannot with `is_base_of`.)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Said another way, `is_base_of<Base, Derived>` is true even with private or ambiguous inheritance (where given a Derived, you cannot easily or uniquely get a Base), but `is_convertible<Derived&, Base&>` is only true for public unambiguous inheritance (where Derived is-a Base).

Comment: I did say "nitpick" :)

Comment: @JeffGarrett `is_convertible`  isn't only true for public unambiguous inheritance (where Derived is-a Base). With `is_convertible` there is no check for inheritance at all. Just because something can be converted into something else it does not mean it provides the same interface as that which it can be converted into. Inheriting from `ostream` and disabling streaming would be bad design. Creating a class that is not derived from an `ostream` (and therefore _is-not-a_) but that can be converted into an `ostream&` would be ok.

Comment: Apologies. In the comment where I wrote it out, I used references (:facepalm:), but the correct idiom uses pointers. `is_convertible<Derived*, Base*>`. Yes, `is_convertible` says nothing about is-a, but combined with other language rules on conversions (for pointers) it tests for is-a (public, unambiguous inheritance). Anyways, it's just a nitpick, that `is_base_of` is almost always wrong.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Ah, yes, now I get what you mean.  Yes, then it makes sense. Added that as an option in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make `operator()` a front-end for the real implementation. You can then make it forward the arguments to the real implementation and add `std::cout` if needed.

Example:

```cpp
struct foo {
    template <class T, class... Args>
    const foo& operator()(T&& first, Args&&... args) const {
        if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<std::ostream, std::remove_reference_t<T>>) {
            // or std::is_convertible_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>*, std::ostream*>

            // first argument is an `ostream`, just forward everything as-is:
            op_impl(std::forward<T>(first), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        } else {
            // add `std::cout` first here:
            op_impl(std::cout, std::forward<T>(first), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        return *this;
    }

 private:
    // implement the full operator function here. `os` is an `ostream` of some sort:
    template <class S, class... Args>
    void op_impl(S&& os, Args&&... args) const {
        (..., (os << args << ' '));
        os << '\n';
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jTeEex3ra)

I used `is_base_of_v<std::ostream, ...>` instead of `is_same` to make it use any `ostream` (like an `ostringstream` or `ofstream`) if supplied as the first argument.

Comment: Nice! Specially the use of `is_base_of_v`.

Comment: Wow, that seems to be the best one! Only one thing: my operator overload must take three arguments and use all them: `T_os& os, const T& first, const Args&... args` so also `first` must be considered.

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Aha, ok, then it's just a matter of adding `first` after `os` in `op_impl`. Should I update the answer to reflect that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just solved adding the missing parameter! Now it works perfectly, many thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a solution with `constexpr if` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)) and [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) will help.

Something like for example the below.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <class TFirst, class... TsRest>
void print(TFirst&& first, TsRest&& ... rest) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v <std::remove_cvref_t<TFirst>, std::ostringstream> or
                  std::is_same_v <std::remove_cvref_t<TFirst>, std::ostream>) {
        ((first << rest << ' '), ...);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << first << ' ';
        ((std::cout << rest << ' '), ...);
    }
}

int main() {

    print(1, 2);

    std::ostringstream oss{};
    print(oss, 3, 4);
    std::cout << "\n\n" << oss.str() << "\n\n";
}
```

Maybe, this could give you an idea . . .